# sort an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I receive an array like that :

```
[
  { league: {id: 2, name: "champions league"}, event: "psg - varsovia", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2},
  { league: {id: 5, name: "world cup"} , event: "belgium - england", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2},
  { league: {id: 2, name: "champions league"}, event: "madrid - fc bruge", scoreteam1: 3, scoreteam:2},
  { league: {id: 2, name: "champions league"}, event: "milan - dortmund", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2},
  { league: {id: 5, name: "world cup"} , event: "japan - danemark", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:5}
]
```

and I would like to get a new array where all the events of the same league are grouped together. What is the best way to do that ?

```
[ 
  { 
   name: "champions league", id: 2, 
   events: 
   [ 
    {"psg - varsovia", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2}, 
    {"milan - dortmund", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2 }, 
    {"madrid - fc bruge", scoreteam1: 3, scoreteam:2}
   ]
  },
  { 
   name: "world cup", id: 5, 
   events: 
   [ 
    {"belgium - england", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2}, 
    {"japan - danemark", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:5}
   ]
  }
]
```

i've done this but its very verbose i think :

```
                     function compareCompetitionId(leagueId, item) {
                            return leagueId === item.competition.id;
                        }
                        function containCompetitionId(leagueId, items) {
                            return items.some(compareCompetitionId.bind(null, leagueId));
                        }
                        function groupByCompetitionId(memo, item) {
                            var leagueId = memo.filter(containCompetitionId.bind(null, item.competition.id));
                            if (leagueId.length > 0) {
                                leagueId[0].push(item);
                            } else {
                                memo.push([item]);
                            }
                            return memo;
                        }
                        // accumulateur
                        var results = list.reduce(groupByCompetitionId, []);
                        console.log(results)
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: check reduce method

Comment: *group together* is something different of sorting. Would you show us the desired output and your attempts?

Comment: i've added an example of what i would like to obtain

Comment: I have a solution for you, but I would like to see your effort first, to see where you stuck

Comment: i've added my actual code but as u can see it's very verbose

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the array of objects and then check each object properties.

When iterating, you see if you already added the new object (the one with the structure you want) looking for `id`, if yes, then just add the event to the `events` array, if not, create a new object and then push it to the resulting and desired array.

```js
let arr = [
  { league: {id: 2, name: "champions league"}, event: "psg - varsovia", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2},
  { league: {id: 5, name: "world cup"} , event: "belgium - england", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2},
  { league: {id: 2, name: "champions league"}, event: "madrid - fc bruge", scoreteam1: 3, scoreteam:2},
  { league: {id: 2, name: "champions league"}, event: "milan - dortmund", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:2},
  { league: {id: 5, name: "world cup"} , event: "japan - danemark", scoreteam1: 1, scoreteam:5}
]
let resultArr = []

for (var obj of arr){
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty("league")){
    if (obj.league.hasOwnProperty("id") && obj.league.hasOwnProperty("name")){
      let existObj = resultArr.find(x => x.id == obj.league.id)
      if (existObj == null){
        let newObj = {}
        newObj.name = obj.league.name
        newObj.id = obj.league.id
        newObj.events = []
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty("event")){
          let event = {}
          event.teams = obj.event;
          event.scoreteam1 = obj.scoreteam1;
          event.scoreteam2 = obj.scoreteam;
          newObj.events.push(event)
        }
        resultArr.push(newObj)
      }
      else{
        if (!existObj.hasOwnProperty("events")){
          existObj.events = []
        }
        let event = {}
        event.teams = obj.event;
        event.scoreteam1 = obj.scoreteam1;
        event.scoreteam2 = obj.scoreteam;
        existObj.events.push(event)
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(resultArr)
```